# Dependent Dropdown is not loading on selection of first dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two dropdown. I am using Jquery to load second dropdown. without jqyery My php code is working fine. but when I use with jquery second dropdown becomes empty on selection of first drop down.

First Dropdown ( Education )

```
$sqleducation = "select * from education order by education_id asc ";
$reseducation = mysqli_query($conn,$sqleducation);

<select name="education" id="education">
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>
<?php while($roweducation=mysqli_fetch_array($reseducation)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $roweducation['education_id']?>">
<?php echo $roweducation['education_name']?>
 </option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

Second Drop Down ( Degree)

```
<select name="degree" id="degree" >
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>

 <?php if(isset($_POST["education_id"]) && !empty($_POST["education_id"])){

$sqldegree = "SELECT * FROM degree WHERE education_id = ".$_POST['education_id']." ";
 $resdegree = mysqli_query($conn,$sqldegree);
while($rowdegree=mysqli_fetch_array($resdegree))
    { ?>

              <option value="<?php echo $rowdegree['degree_id']?>">
              <?php echo $rowdegree['degree_name']?>
              </option>
           <?php } }?>
  </select>
```

Second dropdown is using juery to load on selection of first dropdown Education.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#education').on('change',function(){
    var educationID = $(this).val();
    if(educationID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'education-career.php',
            data:'education_id='+educationID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#degree').html(html);

            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#degree').html('<option value="">Select Education first</option>');

    }
});});</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in ajax, you are using the

```
data:'education_id='+educationID,
```

Which is used to post the data. and the variable name will be here `education_id`.

And in your second page you are trying to get:

```
isset($_POST["education"])
```

this only. So on second page you have to replace `education` with `education_id`.

Comment: I tried it      if(isset($_POST["education_id"]) && !empty($_POST["education_id"]))     but no iffect

Comment: Also you have to change here : `data:'education_id='+educationID,` use this: `data:{ 'education_id' ; educationID},`

Answer (score 1):

Try change below line

```
data:'education_id='+educationID,
```

to

```
data:{education_id : educationID},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.(second select tag have to place in first page in order to use `$('#degree').html(...)`)

First Dropdown

```
$sqleducation = "select * from education order by education_id asc ";
$reseducation = mysqli_query($conn,$sqleducation);

<select name="education" id="education">
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>
<?php while($roweducation=mysqli_fetch_array($reseducation)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $roweducation['education_id']?>">
<?php echo $roweducation['education_name']?>
 </option>
<?php }?>
</select>
<select name="degree" id="degree" >
   <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

Second Dropdown

```
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>

 <?php if(isset($_POST["education_id"]) && !empty($_POST["education_id"])){

$sqldegree = "SELECT * FROM degree WHERE education_id = ".$_POST['education_id']." ";
 $resdegree = mysqli_query($conn,$sqldegree);
while($rowdegree=mysqli_fetch_array($resdegree))
    { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rowdegree['degree_id']?>">
         <?php echo $rowdegree['degree_name']?>
      </option>
   <?php } }?>
```

Comment: what changed did you make ?

Comment: @SaritaSharma, Second select tag have to place in first page in order to use $('#degree').html(...).

Comment: @Star_Man Dude. Check your where condition in second dropdown.

Comment: @CodeLღver, Thanks a lot. I fixed.

Comment: @Star_Man hmm great now fine

Comment: @SaritaSharma, How do you use ajax call? At least, the page called by ajax must be separated from the original page.

Comment: @Star_Man is it necessary to keep seprate ajax page.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$('#education').on('change',function(){
```

To:

```
$('select#education').change(function(){
```